# XSLT - Remove last from the result of a template call

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml as shown below

```
<employee id="e001">
<sal month="jan">
<basic>5000</basic>
<commission>3000</commission>
<sal>
<sal month="feb">
<basic>5000</basic>
<commission>3500</commission>
<sal>
<employee>
```

I want to convert it to xml as shown below.

```
<emp id="e001" sal="5000-3000/5000-3500"></emp>
```

I am calling a template as shown below with parameter employee/*

```
<xsl:template name="salCnsldtd">
    <xsl:param name="list" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$list">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(basic,'-',commission,'/')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The result I am getting after the template call is as below.

```
<emp id="e001" sal="5000-3000/5000-3500/"></emp>
```

How can I remove the last slash(/) from sal. Please help me with a better solution or to remove the slash. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template name="salCnsldtd">
  <xsl:param name="list" />
  <xsl:variable name="compensation">
    <xsl:for-each select="$list">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',basic,'-',commission)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="substr($compensation,2)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I moved the delimiter "`/`" to the front of each element and then stripped off the first one in the final string.

Comment: Thanks alot Jim. It worked. I am using xslt 1.0 so I changed substr to substring. that is it.